# Querying Files in Apex, Classic vs Lightning

Tags: apex, lightning, files

I have a Site User who accesses records through a VF page. I am encountering a strange problem where, Files uploaded in Lightning is visible but not the files those were uploaded in Classic.

When debugged, SOQL query is returning all in Execute Anonymous, but Debug Logs show only limited (uploaded in Lightning).

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> docList = [select ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.title from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId =:recordId];
system.debug('docList: ' + docList);
```

I found that there is "working as designed" behavior while deleting a File - Lightning vs Classic - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000270734&language=en_US&type=1. Wondering if my issue is similar to this issue!

Any idea how to solve this? More importantly any idea why this is happening?

Comment: In classic may be they are uploading file in Attachment. Did you checked that?

Comment: Yes, I am uploading in Files only. We have removed Attachments related list. I uploaded same file in both Lightning and Classic, when viewed only Lightning uploaded files are shown for the user in Site.

Comment: Not exactly but similar issue I was getting, issue was when we were uploading the file from Classic, "Visibility" fields was not being assigned correctly on ConentDocumentLink (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) and this field is responsible for it's visibility.  Can you please check on that.  https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YruAAE

Comment: Thanks Ayub. I had gone through these to double check the property differences between files. To my surprise they are all exactly same (ShareType=V, Visibility=AllUsers)

Comment: Maybe on the `ContentVersion` object - you have the `ContentLocation` field: 'S'=within Salesforce, 'E'=External

Comment: ContentVersion is queried using ContentDocumentId from the previous query. Since the query itself is returning only the files uploaded in Lightning, I can't do anything further (by checking ContentVersion object).